# How to make C++ https downloader proxy aware

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to rewrite an internal application in C++ but have run into a speed bump. My C++ code is not able to reach through our company proxy, while the C# application is. I have attached both codes so you can see the difference.

C++ is not my main language, so my question is: Does anyone know how to make the C++ version proxy aware?

C++:

```cpp
using namespace std;

string downloader(char *url) {
    IStream *stream;
    HRESULT result = URLOpenBlockingStream(0, url, &stream, 0, 0);
    if (result != 0) {
        return "";
    }
    char buffer[100];
    unsigned long bytesRead;
    stringstream ss;
    stream->Read(buffer, 100, &bytesRead);
    while (bytesRead > 0U) {
        ss.write(buffer, (long long)bytesRead);
        stream->Read(buffer, 100, &bytesRead);
    }
    stream->Release();
    string resultString = ss.str();
    cout << resultString << endl;
    return resultString;
}
```

Here is the C# code that is proxy aware:

```cs
public static  void DownloadString(string address)
      {
          WebClient client = new WebClient();
          client.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
          client.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
          string website = client.DownloadString(address);
                
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser can give you the proxy configuration for internet explorer, UrlMkSetSessionOption can set the proxy options.

Just search the functions you're using on Google, you'll find documentation pretty easily.

Comment: WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser is interesting but will fail if the code is run as system (as this will be). UrlMkSetSessionOption could be ok as a fall back, although I would be interested to see if anyone has an automated way of doing it similar to the c# example! Thanks Wutz

Comment: Docs say: This function should not be used in a service process that does not impersonate a logged-on user. But GetSystemWebProxy from your c# example also fetches the proxy settings from ie for the currently impersonated user. Why does one work in your scenario but not the other?

Comment: You make a good point. Perhaps my implemenation of it is wrong! How would you implement it using my above C++ example @Wutz?

Comment: You mean maybe your c# implementation is wrong? In that case I'll need more information, because as the question stands right now, the c# code shows what the goal is. If that's not the goal, you'll have to tell us what it is. Where should the proxy data come from?